# Como funciona a matrix3d() em CSS?

Tags: php, javascript, java, html, css

Bom, eu sei que para trabalhar com a `matrix()`é seguido por 6 métodos de transformação 2D em apenas um único método. Se eu tivesse o seguinte código `matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)`. Cada número representaria um método que estaria nesta ordem `matrix(scaleX(), skewY(), skewX(), scaleY(), translateX(), translateY())`.
Só que e se eu estivesse trabalhando com uma transformação em 3D e precisasse utilizar a `matrix3d()` e tivesse o seguinte código `matrix3d(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1);` qual é a ordem desses 16 métodos?

Comment: Acho que isso pode te interessar https://www.useragentman.com/blog/2015/07/16/augment-photos-with-css3-matrix3d-transforms/